# Setting default folder for "Open a file"

Tags: gnome, nautilus, filemanager

I deactivated "Recent files" with this: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false`

Now, every time I click on a "Browse files" from a browser, the `/home/` directory opens.

[image]

Is it possible to select the folder that will open when you click "Browse files"?

I'm doing this because this File Chooser doesn't remember the last folder I used, meaning that I have to click that folder each time I want to upload another file from that folder.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu).

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting to enable/disable "remember recent files" in dconf-editor which can be installed by `sudo apt install dconf-editor`. Toggle the  setting for *remember-recent-files* back on as shown in the below screenshot. *remember-app-usage* should be set to "on" too.

[image]

If you have a favorite folder that you often upload files from you can drag it into the left pane of Files file browser to be able to find it quickly and make it easier to browse to.

Comment: That was the the setup I had before. And the File Explorer kept showing me "Recent Files" instead of the folder of the last file I uploaded. That's why I disabled `remember-recent-files`, hoping I could choose the default folder of the File Explorer (when opened with a browser).

Comment: If you have a favorite folder that you often upload files from you can drag it into the left pane of Files file browser to make it easier to browse to.